# What are some good resources for the Web Forms MVP project?

Tags: asp.net, open-source, webforms, mvp

I've seen a little buzz on the open-source ASP.NET Web Forms MVP project, but where can I get resources?

http://webformsmvp.com is pretty much stubbed out for now.  This appears to be a compelling refresh of the Web Forms paradigm and bring into the fold things that make ASP.NET MVC great.  I hear it's going to be put out there at MIX10 this week, but anyone have any useful sites/references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tatham Oddie, one of the WebForms MVP developers, was on Scott Hanselman's podcast not too long ago. You can find that episode here: [A different way to do ASP.NET WebForms with WebFormsMVP](http://hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=220). A PDF transcript is available there if you don't have time to listen to it.

Tatham's blog is at http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/ and his most recent post mentions the podcast and that they were quite about the project till now. The wiki page on the project's site that you linked to mentions the MIX 10 announcement.

You can find the video and slides of Tatham's and Damian's MIX10 session here (they do mention WebForms MVP near the end of the slides): [Building Great Standards-Based Websites for the Big Wide World with Microsoft ASP.NET 4](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX20).

Apart from that, and the [project's wiki page](http://wiki.webformsmvp.com/index.php?title=Main_Page), I don't think there are any other resources. They suggest downloading the project demo to get familiar with it till documentation is available.

Answer (score 1):

I am also not aware of this project - domain was registered long ago it seems but if you google for it there are not many results.

If you want to use MVP I can highly recommend you the following article by Billy McCafferty:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/ModelViewPresenter.aspx

Maybe you mix it up with what is extracted now from the ASP.NET MVC framework that goes into the "classic" ASP.NET - e.g. URL Routing functionality which you can read up there:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Maybe this helps but I have not heard about any MVP project - and the one linked in your questions seems to have no relation to Microsoft (if you look it up on nic.com)